# Read data from a dictionary in pandas and assign new column value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have `dict` data in a pandas column and I am attempting to assign values to a new column from the `dict`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'n': [np.nan, np.nan],
                   'd': [{'status': {'version': '1.0.0'},
                          'p': [{'identifier': {'Id': 5155,
                          'fips': '07',
                          'aId': 5175},
                          'lt': {'ltnum': '14',
                          'ls1': 0.1485537,
                          'ls2': 6471,
                          'ptype': 'NO'}}]}, 
                          np.nan]
                 })
```

When I try:

```
df['n'].fillna(df['d'].str['p'][0][0]['lt']['ls1'], inplace=True)
```

I get a:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Your example currently produces a different error. `ls1` is a key inside a dictionary with `lt` as key, that's not shown in your code.

Comment: @AlexK updated the question. Basically, when I take this approach I am getting the `TypeError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `str` accessor everytime:

```
df['n'].fillna(df['d'].str['p'].str[0].str['lt'].str['ls1'], inplace=True)
print(df)

# Output
          n                                                  d
0  0.148554  {'status': {'version': '1.0.0'}, 'p': [{'ident...
1       NaN                                                NaN
```

Comment: @kms. I updated my answer, can you check it please?

Comment: why do I need `str` accessor everytime?

Comment: Else `str['p'][0]` means the first row of the Series while `str['p'].str[0]` means the first element of each row. And so on.